# import data from xml into database

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-xml

i would like to import data into my database through an xml file:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(XMLFile);
var nodes = from e in doc.Descendants("Person")
                    where e.Element("PersonID").Value == "1"
                    select e;
```

The person table has same structure as the data from nodes. Is it handy to use entity framework/linq-to-xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML's format is right - i.e. if it uses the same format that the `DataSet` uses - you can just read it using `DataSet.ReadXml()` and then use all of the normal ADO tools for inserting the data into your database.  Though it really helps if you've actually generated the XML from a `DataSet` in the first place and thus have a schema for `ReadXml` to use, because that resolves a lot of data type conversion issues that you'd otherwise have to take care of explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by "handy", but it is certainly possible.

You can map the `XElement` nodes to your LINQtoSQL/EF-generated objects quite easily, if the schemas match.

Your above code should result in an `IEnumerable<XElement>` with the `XName` "Person",

so from there you just need to do something like

```
  IEnumerable<Person> people = nodes.Select(xe => new Person { 
                          PersonID = int.Parse(xe.Element("PersonID").Value), 
                          OtherProperty = xe.Element("OtherProperty").Value
                                 });
```

You will need to do some conversions like the `int.Parse()` for some datatypes, because `XElement.Value` returns a string.

Then to save it to the database, let's assume `MyDataContext` is a LINQ to SQL generated `DataContext` object with a property `People` that is a `Table<Person>`.  All you have to do is:

```
  MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
  db.People.InsertAllOnSubmit(people);
  db.SubmitChanges();
```