# XML to XSD to C# Class To SQL Database

Tags: xml, entity-framework, xsd

Is there a way to convert an XML file to a nice database architecture?

These are the steps I have done so far:

1 - Create an XSD File from my XML File : `xsd MyFile.xml`
2 - Create a C# Class from my xsd file : `xsd MyFile.xsd /classes`
3 - I can now deserialize my xml file in my class.

```
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassXml));
    MyClassXml oMyClassXml;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(PathToXML))
    {
        oMyClassXml = (MyClassXml) ser.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

At this point, I would like to convert my XSD to SQL Server tables.
And finally, create entities that reflect these new tables by doing `Update Model From Database`.
At the end of the day, I will be able to import my XML file into my SQL Server database.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535270/import-data-from-xml-into-database

Answer (score 0):

> And finally, create entities that reflect these new tables by doing Update Model From Database.

That is the step you are doing wrong. Instead of making the database schema to generate classes use classes to generate database schema from using Entity Framework "[Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)".

All you need to do is create a DbContext containing the classes generated from `xsd.exe`, you may want to also tweak the classes to support things like Lazy Loading and Navigation Properties, but you can find out more information about that from [Entity Framework's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723).

Comment: I know old post - but how would op "create a DbContext containing the classes" automagically - suppose an op has 100 classes , or multiple relations , isn't it easier to use a tool for such things instead of boiler plate code.. Just saying ..